# How to make downward triangke looping from number 5 to 1

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How to make downward triangle from 5 to 1

```
function segitiga(baris) {
  let pola = '';
  for (let i = 1; i <= baris; i++) {
    for (let j = baris; j >= i; j--) {
      pola += i;
    }
    pola += '\n';
  } return pola;
} console.log(segitiga(5));
```

Output

```
11111
2222
333
44
5
```

I want the output can be like this

Output:

```
55555
4444
333
22
1
```

Comment: How about `pola += i;` -> `pola += (baris + 1 - i);` ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the calculation for pola in the inner loop and tweak the two loops for easier understanding like so:

```
function segitiga(baris) {
    let pola = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < baris; i++) {
        for (let j = baris; j > i; j--) {
            pola += baris - i;
        }
        pola += "\n";
    }
    return pola;
}
```

You can also try an easier approach using javascript array methods like so:

```
const segitiga = (baris = 1) => {
    let current = baris;
    return new Array(baris)
        .fill(null)
        .map((_, idx) => new Array(current--).fill(baris - idx).join(""))
        .join("\n");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your outer loop to count down from `baris` to one, so it needs to start at baris and then reduce by one each iteration until it reaches one. Your inner loop needs to loop i times, so you should be able to use a fairly basic for loop to account for that.

```js
function segitiga(baris) {
  let pola = '';
  // start i at baris, carry on while i >= 1, reduce i by 1 each iteration
  for (let i = baris; i >= 1; i--) {
    // loop i times
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      pola += i;
    }
    pola += '\n';
  }
  return pola;
}

console.log(segitiga(5));
```

Included below is a version using the String [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method, in case it's interesting.

```js
const segitiga2 = (baris) =>
  Array.from({ length: baris }, (_, i) => ((baris - i) + '').repeat(baris - i))
    .join("\n");

console.log(segitiga2(5));
```